# Broadcast value accessed inside foreachPartition

Tags: apache-spark

In a Driver I have created a val to broadcast which gets created no issue:

```
val some_val = 100
val some_val_BC = sc.broadcast(some_val)
```

However, inside a foreachPartition construct, if I try to access in any way the some_val_BC and use it, I get Task not serializable error.

I understand Broadcast JOIN for sure, and this example:

```
 rdd.map(i => broadcasted.value.contains(i))
```

but what about? :

```
val x = some_val_BC.value
```

I can't see the reason why. Unless it must be used with map.

Comment: I'm not Spark expert, however I think the reason is that `sc.broadcast` will initialize your variable on the driver, however when you call `foreachPartition` then you're trying to use the initialized variable on each worker node, and therefore Spark will try to serialize the object in order to send it through the workers, so if the object is not serialized you will get the serializable error. But for RDD closures, e.g. RDD transformations like `map`, `filter` or `flatMap` the process of packaging everything up, serialization and sending to worker nodes is somehow already implicit.

Comment: Concurs with my last statement on question.

Comment: Not sure about the suggested song, however

Comment: Haha, if you mean my website to suggest a song, the database contains only 50 songs :) because it's just a toy machine learning project. There's a button to share your favorite song in case you don't like the suggested song. It would be nice to have your recommendation ready for others! ;)

Comment: Will look during my vacation and add it. On a more serious note, I feel there is a gap with SPARK with all this Serialization stuff. It's also hard to follow.

Comment: I also faced the task not serializable error before while trying to use loops and/or maps and I used to solve it by serializing my object, for example adding the line `object yourObject extends java.io.Serializable{...}`. I don't think the serialization stuff is a gap. Nested RDD's, that is a serious gap!

Comment: I move all things inside map, etc.

Comment: Unclear why a close would be issued. On topic if I look at the question